# Python urllib 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2757' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, urllib

Here's my code

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
try:
      link = 'https://shopee.com.my/❗-❗-READY-STOCK-❗-❗-UA-UNDER-ARMO-DRAWSTRING-BAG-WATERPROOF-i.48885154.1199018006'
      return opener.open(link).read()
  except Exception as e:
      print('Exception: ' + str(e))
      exit()
```

I'm trying to read [this URL](https://shopee.com.my/%E2%9D%97-%E2%9D%97-READY-STOCK-%E2%9D%97-%E2%9D%97-UA-UNDER-ARMO-DRAWSTRING-BAG-WATERPROOF-i.48885154.1199018006), but then I got the error

```
Exception: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2757' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any way to read the URL with special character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module, recommended by the official documentation. It makes also that easier:

```
import requests

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/❗-❗-READY-STOCK-❗-❗-UA-UNDER-ARMO-DRAWSTRING-BAG-WATERPROOF-i.48885154.1199018006'

data = requests.get(url)

print(data.text)
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>

    <script>
    // QOS start time must be as early as possible.
    var QOS_PAGE_START_MS = Date.now ? Date.now() : +new Date();
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="mJTGLsUwODg98nXhwcsYGJuVana8TPIz9iUNiniILPM" />
    .....
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse


opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
try:
    link = 'https://shopee.com.my/' + urllib.parse.quote_plus('❗-❗-READY-STOCK-❗-❗-UA-UNDER-ARMO-DRAWSTRING-BAG-WATERPROOF-i.48885154.1199018006')
    print(link)
    print(opener.open(link).read())
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception: ' + str(e))
    exit()
```

It will encode the URL

```
https://shopee.com.my/%E2%9D%97-%E2%9D%97-READY-STOCK-%E2%9D%97-%E2%9D%97-UA-UNDER-ARMO-DRAWSTRING-BAG-WATERPROOF-i.48885154.1199018006
```

but unfortunately still fail since `shopee.com.my` seems to have an invalid https certificate:

```
Exception: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)>
```